shrink the grid item when screen is minimized
I have implemented angular-gridster2 to hold several widgets. They all work fine and are in place when displayed in the browser. But when the same view is used in mobile view, they are stacked one upon another.
Is  it possible to shrink the grids when size of window is minimized .Also disable the stacking of grid.
